# VB Class passing shared variables

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, authentication

I have a class that I use to connect to a SQL Server to perform various functions.  As it is now it works fine however I had to use a dim statement define a connection string for all subroutines that make a db call.  I was tying to avoid this but no luck.  My goal is to provide the userid and password once (hence shared members).  So every time the class is instantiated the UID and PWD will be shared and the DBCon string need only be defined once a the to of the class.

Unfortunately the DBCon does not work when it's defined as a private variable.  The UID and PWD work fine however.  How do I correct this?  I have not been abe to find any examples on the web as to the right way to do this.

This is the class as it stands.

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
 
Public Class SQLControl
    Public Shared UID As String
    Public Shared PWD As String
 
    **'This string does not work**
    **'Private DBCon As New SqlConnection("Server=JABDWVC0496,1733;Database=testdb;User=" & UID & ";Pwd=" & PWD & ";")**
    Private DBCmd As SqlCommand                                         'Database command that will run against the query
 
    'Database data
    Public DBDA As SqlDataAdapter
    Public DBDT As DataTable
 
    Public Params As New List(Of SqlParameter)                          'Query parameters
 
    'Query statistics
    Public RecordCount As Integer
    Public ColumnCount As Integer
    Public Exception As String
 
    Public Sub TestCon()                                                'Test the connection to the database.
        **strong text**'I have to repeat this line in all subroutines that access the DB
        **strong text**Dim DBCon As New SqlConnection("Server=JABDWVC0496,1733;Database=ptslcmdev;User=" & UID & ";Pwd=" & PWD & ";")
        Try
            DBCon.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Exception = "Connection Error: " & vbNewLine & ex.Message   'Error message
        Finally
            If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()    'Close connection
        End Try
    End Sub
 
    Public Sub New()                                                    'Uses the default connection to be 
    End Sub
 
    Public Sub New(ConnectionString As String)                          'Allow cnnection string override
        Dim DBCon As New SqlConnection
        DBCon = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    End Sub
 
    Public Sub ExecQuery(Query As String)                               'Run the query
        Dim DBCon As New SqlConnection("Server=JABDWVC0496,1733;Database=ptslcmdev;User=" & UID & ";Pwd=" & PWD & ";")
        'Reset the stats that are collected
        RecordCount = 0
        Exception = ""
 
        Try
            DBCon.Open()                                                'Opens the connection to the database
            DBCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, DBCon)                        'Assemble the command t be executed
            Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(p))              'Append the parameters to the command
            Params.Clear()                                              'Clear the parameters since the are added to the command
 
            DBDT = New DataTable                                        'Create the Data Table to hld the results
            DBDA = New SqlDataAdapter(DBCmd)                            'Executed the command
            RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)                               'Populate the Temp Db Table
            ColumnCount = DBDT.Columns.Count
 
        Catch ex As Exception
            Exception = "ExecQuery Error: " & vbNewLine & ex.Message    'Capture the error if one occurs
        Finally
            If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()    'Close the connection to the database
        End Try
    End Sub
 
    'This is the routine to stage the parameters for the database command
    Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
        Dim NewParam As New SqlParameter(Name, Value)
        Params.Add(NewParam)
    End Sub
 
    'Error checking
    Public Function HasException(Optional Report As Boolean = False) As Boolean
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Exception) Then Return False
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: In future, please don't post ALL your code. Only post what's relevant to the issue. If you haven't narrowed it down then you haven't considered the problem carefully enough. Please read [thiis](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your case, the important part is "minimal", i.e. no more than is required to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Saying that something doesn't work is never enough. You have to tell us EXACTLY what actually does happen. As far as I can see, what you had should work fine, as long as you set those `Shared` fields before creating an instance of that class. If you do that and it still doesn't work as expected, you need to debug your code and provide specific details of what happens and how that differs from your expectation. Then we will know what we're looking for.

Comment: Connections and commands need to be disposed in the method where they are used so it is not correct to use class level variables for these objects. You are trying to make a single procedure do all types of work. What if it is a Delete query? Learn to use Using...End Using blocks. Parameters need an SqlDbType.

Comment: When I uncomment the the DBCon variable at the top of the class and comment out the Dim DBCon statements in the Subroutines;
The login fails, when I run a debug on the DBCon connection string the variables UID and PWD are not populating so the string (in debugger watch) shows up as this

Server=JABDWVC0496,1733;Database=testdb;User=;Pwd=;

The shared fields are being populated before I call the TestCon() and when I check them they are populated.  So it appears the statement is not using the variables.

Comment: Who cares whether they are being set before you call that method? They need to be set before you create the instance, as I said in my previous comment. The code that creates the connection object is executed when the instance is created so those fields need to be set before that happens. There's no reason not to do that so do it. For future reference, please direct replies to the person who made the comment, so they get a notification. You do that by typing the @ character and then typing their name. You'll be prompted to select a matching as soon as you type a character.